# Why is Flink HA cluster on YARN recovered more than the maximum number of attempts?

Tags: hadoop-yarn, apache-flink

Using Flink 1.7.2 and YARN 2.8, I'm testing Flink cluster’s recovery feature, and Flink High Availability cluster was recovered beyond the max attempts time in my environment.

I set `yarn.resourcemanager.am.max-attempts` , which is YARN’s configuration property, to `2`, and `yarn.application-attempts`, which is Flink’s configuration property, to `5`.

At 1st, I deployed Flink session cluster with **NON HA** settings to YARN, and I stopped JobManager with kill command.
Flink cluster resulted into **FAILED** state after stopping JobManager twice.
I think, the value of `yarn.resourcemanager.am.max-attempts` was affecting to that behavior.

However, when I deployed HA Flink Cluster, Flink cluster was recovered even if I stopped JobManager more than 5 times.
YARN increment application’s attempt number and recover Flink cluster and pipeline job repeatedly.
I wonder why Flink cluster can be recovered more than both of `yarn.resourcemanager.am.max-attempts` and `yarn.application-attempts` value.

Is this the expected behavior?

Here is my `flink-conf.yaml` for HA cluster:

```
state.backend: filesystem
state.checkpoints.dir: hdfs:///user/kmoti/.flink/checkpoints
state.savepoints.dir: hdfs:///user/kmoti/.flink/savepoints

high-availability: zookeeper
high-availability.zookeeper.quorum: zookeeper1:2181,zookeeper2:2181,zookeeper3:2181
high-availability.zookeeper.path.root: /flink
high-availability.storageDir: hdfs:///user/kmoti/.flink/recovery
yarn.application-attempts: 5
```

and here is for NON HA cluster:

```
state.backend: filesystem
state.checkpoints.dir: hdfs:///user/kmoti/.flink/checkpoints
state.savepoints.dir: hdfs:///user/kmoti/.flink/savepoints
yarn.application-attempts: 5
```

Does anyone know how attempts time will be count in Flink HA cluster ?

### Following section is updated at Jun 10 '19

I asked this question at [flink user mailing list](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/221d57b6bb86b9e0488fa1587f464c61356fcce16b50e6d5a2525610@%3Cuser.flink.apache.org%3E), and I get answer that YARN will not count attempt time when use kill to stop process as detailed [here](http://johnjianfang.blogspot.com/2015/04/the-number-of-maximum-attempts-of-yarn.html).

However, when using NON HA mode, Flink cluster failed after second time kill command to stop JobManager.
I seems that JobManager's failure is counted only when using NON HA cluster mode.
Does anyone know the reason of this behavior?

Comment: Yarn will take the minimum from `yarn.resourcemanager.am.max-attempts` and `yarn.application-attempts`. If HA is disabled, then Flink will set the application attempts to `1`. Maybe the Hadoop logs could give some insights why the Flink application is restarted more often than `2` times.

Comment: @Till Rohrmann Thank you for your advice.


In [Flink document](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/jobmanager_high_availability.html#maximum-application-master-attempts-yarn-sitexml), it is said that If yarn.resourcemanager.am.max-attempts is set to 2, it meaning that a single JobManager failure is tolerated(2 attempts means 1 initial attempt and 1 retry).
In my NON HA cluster , after second kill command to stop JobManager, Flink Cluster was failed.
That is why, in my understand, NON HA cluster set max-attempts time to 2 and cluster work correctly.
Is this wrong?